# React Native + Android: Why do I get this message ":app:processDebugResources FAILED" and how to solve it?

Tags: android, react-native

After building up my app using *react-native run-android*, I get the following error messages:

app\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:2: AAPT: Tag  attribute package has invalid character '-'.

app\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:18: AAPT: Tag  attribute name has invalid character '-'.

app\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:24: AAPT: Tag  attribute name has invalid character '-'.

app\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:2: Tag  attribute package has invalid character '-'.
\app\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:18: Tag  attribute name has invalid character '-'.
app\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:24: Tag  attribute name has invalid character '-'.

:app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Could you please advise on how to resolve this issue?

I thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the dashes were the source of the issue. Replaced them with '.' to make it work.